# working with multindexes in pandas, finding the 3 maximum for each subindex and outputting the data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with a multindex

[image: dataframe picture]

how do i find the top 3 counties for each states with the highest population, i tried using a for loop and pandas.max, but couldn't manage to make it work.
The Question is how do i find the indexes of based on the population data.

Comment: Make a complete question that doesn't require clicking links please.

Comment: thats how images work in this website is not really a link, just an image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bw5c.png

Comment: No, that's not how images work here. I fixed it for you so you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't access your picture because of the webfilter at work.

However, you are probably looking for something like:

`dataframe.sort_values("Population", inplace = True, ascending = False)`

and then display them with:

`dataframe.head(3)`

Comment: yes but it's a multindex, and i have `census_df.set_index(['STNAME', 'CTYNAME'])` 2 indexes, i need the top 3 `'CTYNAME'` by population for each state `'STNAME'`